# Filtering [[String]] with a regex and pattern matching

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to filter a [[String]] based upon a regex.

```
filter (\fn -> case (matchRegex (mkRegex "*.exe") fn) of Nothing -> False
                                                         Just _ -> True) 
       directory_info
```

Unfortunately, the lambda function is syntactically invalid here: a pattern match can not occur in expression context, according to ghc.

How should this be rephrased to concisely execute the intended meaning?

Comment: I don't understand from why you're getting that error from that code (and I'll go with hammar's answer anyway) but you could avoid the pattern matching by using `isJust` from Data.Maybe.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why use regex when you have [`System.FilePath`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/filepath/latest/doc/html/System-FilePath.html)? In this case, try the [`takeExtension`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/filepath/latest/doc/html/System-FilePath-Posix.html#v:takeExtension) function.

```
filter (\fn -> takeExtension fn == ".exe") directory_info
```

Comment: Definitely the best approach. Regex is not the best tool in this case.

Answer (score 6):

First off, your regex is wrong. It should be `".*\\.exe"`. What you're using is called globbing.

Second, try using the `=~` syntax instead, examples [here](http://www.serpentine.com/blog/2007/02/27/a-haskell-regular-expression-tutorial/).

For example, this should work:

```
filter (\fn -> fn =~ ".*\\.exe" :: Bool) directory_info
```

Also, you don't have to use a lambda. Turn it into a function and it might work.

Answer (score 4):

If you are only interested if there is a match, you could use [`matchTest`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/regex-base/latest/doc/html/Text-Regex-Base-RegexLike.html#v%3amatchTest) instead of `matchRegex`.